# Adding tab stops to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, tabstop, winnovative

We use a library called Winnovative to create PDFs with inputs for digital signatures. I'm wondering if it is possible, and how, to add tab stops at these locations. I wish I could provide some kind of proof of an attempt, but I really don't even know where to start, here. Any information related to creating tab stops would be helpful.

I know this question is a bit vague -- if it is bothersome-ly vague, please suggest a way to edit it so I can improve the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "tab stops at these locations" --- which "these locations"? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: @mkl sorry - at the locations of the signature inputs. I want to stop at a certain location (the where of this is unimportant in the scope of the question, as I'll have to figure that out myself)

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, but allow me to state that an integrated pdf signature signs everything but the space left for the signature container bytes themselves. If you want to prepare multiple signature fields, though, they can be located wherever you want.

Comment: @mkl not sure what you meant there, but I already have the signature locations in there and working. I just want it to stop on them when the user hits the tab key

Comment: Ah, Ok, then i completely misunderstood what you meant, i thought you wanted to get tab stops when creating the pdfs for layout purposes.